# Definite integral: $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} {x^{1000}\sin x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^{1000}\sin x\,dx?$$

As I understand, the definite integral equals to $0$. However, what are the ways to show that properly?

Answer (score 4):

The function is odd and $[-\pi; \pi]$ is symmetric around the origin so the integral is $0$

Answer (score 2):

You may just write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} {x^{1000}\sin x}dx&=\int_{-\pi}^0{x^{1000}\sin x}dx+\int_0^{\pi} {x^{1000}\sin x}dx\\\\
&=\int_{\pi}^0{(-x)^{1000}\sin (-x)}(-dx)+\int_0^{\pi} {x^{1000}\sin x}dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^\pi{x^{1000}\sin x}dx+\int_0^{\pi} {x^{1000}\sin x}dx\\\\
&=0.\end{align}
$$
You may check that this is in fact a particular case of a general fact

> $$
> \int_{-a}^af(x)\:dx=0
> $$

for all integrable odd functions $f$.